# How do I keep Javascript Parsley from submitting when a button (not submit) is clicked?

Tags: javascript, button, submit, parsley

I'm using Parsley to validate forms. I'm using 2.8 wbich is a more current version. When any button on my form is clicked (even it's not submit), Parsley will trigger a submit. For example I have this button which clears an uploaded photo.

```
<button id='attached-clear' onclick="App.clearPhoto('#attached')")
Clear
</button>
```

This will trigger a "submit" when Parsley is enabled. So when the user tries to clear the form it is submitted instead. I tried various options on the form of:

```
<form ... data-parsley-excluded='input[type=button]' ..>
```

And:

```
<button data-parsley-excluded="" ...>
```

But it always submits. If I disable parsley then I don't have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add button `type= 'button'`, submit is default value for type [**MDN ref**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

```html
<form>
 <button type='button' onclick="console.log('hello')">Clear</button>
</form>
```